# Proper way to convert BOOL value into INT?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, int, boolean, type-conversion

Everytime when I tried to convert BOOL value into int. INT value is showing -8 for True and 0 for False. Ideally it should return 1 for true.

I have tried all possible ways of conversion like

```
int val=Info.isattachementDownloadable;
int val=[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", Info.isattachementDownloadable] intValue];
int val=(int)Info.isattachementDownloadable;
```

where `Info.isattachementDownloadable` return BOOL

In all ways its showing -8 for TRUE.

Any suggestion ?

Comment: i did simple `int intVar = boolVar;` and it takes the correct value in int, i.e. 1 for 1 and 0 for 0

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Maybe that will help(thought i don't know why it may be needed in the first place)

```
NSInteger i = @(YES).integerValue;
```

Hope that it helps you.

Comment: Great that i was looking for :) ... i dont know why i missed this one :(

Comment: I will point out that, for code that requires high efficiency, this is a poor method of converting a BOOL to an int because it **allocates** an object every time a conversion takes place.

Comment: I agree, that it isn't fastest, nor memory friendly method, but it's objc straightest one that I know. Anyway, if you need efficiency - you can always fall back to plain c with `int myInt = (someBool ? 1 : 0);` as you've suggested in your answer. :)

Comment: @AlexNichol [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] returns a singleton. There is a maximum of one allocation no matter how many times you call that.

Comment: This can be needed when you for example want to use the tag-property on a UIButton as a BOOL - whether the button is recently pressed or not. Then you don't need to declare any extra property for this in the controller.

Answer (score 22):

It is much quicker to do it like this:

```
BOOL myBool = YES;
int myInt = (myBool ? 1 : 0);
```

`myInt` will be 1 if `myBool` is YES, and 0 if `myBool` is NO.

Comment: Or even better, `myBool!=0`, or JavaScript's patented `!!myBool`.

Comment: I may be wrong but don't BOOL's auto convert to this int value anyways in Obj-c when used as an int? For example NSLog(@"%i", YES+YES); logs 2

Answer (score 2):

It is always possible to use the object-oriented wrapper around numeric primitives (e.g. C's int). So am I answering the question? both yes and no depending on your viewpoint. However, here is what I prefer to use when using BOOL as input:

```
NSNumber *numval = [NSNumber numberWithBool:Info.isattachementDownloadable];
```

And if you really need to use the primitive datatype:

```
int val = [numval intValue];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
BOOL myBool;    
int myInt;
if (myBool) myInt = 1;
else myInt = 0;
```

Comment: this is pretty straightforward... but you are not doing any conversion ... is it conversion not possible ?

Answer (score 1):

You can just assign BOOL value to int since YES and NO are just shortcuts for 1 and 0. You can also perform maths operations on BOOLs.
FYI, BOOLs can even hold values from -128 up to 127 since they are just typedefs for signed chars.

```
BOOL someBool = YES;
int intFromBool = someBool;
NSLog(@"%d", intFromBool);

intFromBool -= YES;
NSLog(@"%d", intFromBool);
```

Reference: https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/bools-sharp-corners/